# firefox extension status bar overlay run

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to make my first Firefox addon and am struggling a bit.

I have written the javascript code for what I want it to do (window.alert("hello world!")).  I have found code to make a thing on the status bar:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Creating_a_status_bar_extention. Now, I want to make it so that a user can click on the status bar part and it will run my hello world alert.  I have spent 3 hours looking and have found nothing.

How can I make my status bar thing run my javascript?

Comment: Note that the status bar is going away soon: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_add-on_bar

Comment: @MatrixFrog it's not going away, it's just being hidden by default, altough it's very easy to set it back

Comment: No, it is going away, and being replaced by the addon bar. The addon bar is not the same thing as the status bar because it doesn't show status information, and anyway, it has a different id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onclick` attribute to your statusbarpanel, with the function you want to call. Then make sure the function is defined in a script which is included in your overlay.

Comment: I thought I had tried this, but I was wrong.  onclick worked! Thanks